# Custom UTF8 text decoder for old text file

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have some old text documents that I'm trying to convert into UTF8 with Python. It has a .DOC extension, and it was written using a Tandy 1000. I haven't been able to find what kind of encoding it uses, so I'm thinking it was some Deskmate proprietary encoding. The majority of the text is ascii symbols, and a small minority are non-ascii characters. For example, see this `xxd` output:

```
2073 6f75 6c73 a9a9 a920 636f 6d70 6172   souls... compar
```

Using a printed version of the document, I can map the non-ascii bytes to their unicode characters. For example, in the above `xxd` output, 0xa9 is an em dash. There are many other examples of these non-ascii characters that I can manually map to utf8.

Any suggestions on the most elegant approach to decoding these characters? Right now I have the file loaded in a Python `bytearray`, and I'm wondering if there's a away to give the `.decode("utf8")` function a map to show that, say, `0xa9` is `0x2014` (i.e., em dash)?

For reference, here are the outputs of `chardetect`:

```
$ chardetect *DOC
file1.DOC   : ascii with confidence 1.0
file2.DOC   : ISO-8859-1 with confidence 0.7266894615606104
file3.DOC   : ascii with confidence 1.0
file4.DOC   : ascii with confidence 1.0
file5.DOC   : Windows-1252 with confidence 0.7184626436781609
file6.DOC   : Windows-1252 with confidence 0.7278633198811477
file7.DOC   : Windows-1252 with confidence 0.726540670123209
file8.DOC   : ISO-8859-1 with confidence 0.7252491632577166
file9.DOC   : Windows-1252 with confidence 0.7268076883962168
file10.DOC  : Windows-1252 with confidence 0.7252083189387135
file11.DOC  : Windows-1252 with confidence 0.7270349029424267
file12.DOC  : ISO-8859-1 with confidence 0.73
file13.DOC  : KOI8-R with confidence 0.8191677051323929
```

Comment: I would decode with (as example (cp437, or any 8-bit encoding with all 256 value encoded) (so you get a string). Then I'll use `maketrans()`

Comment: The Tandy 1000 was likely [`cp437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) encoding (the original IBM PC encoding).  That decodes as `' souls⌐⌐⌐ compar'`.

Comment: `—` (U+2014,  *Em Dash*) does not map to `\xa9` in any Python encoding (afaik). `b"\xa9"` could be decoded to one of the following characters `z ⌐ ر σ ® ę Е Ò ﺏ й Ζ ฉ ｩ ۸ © Š İ Љ Đ ╘` (trying to apply all known Python [standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)).

Comment: For instance, `bytes.fromhex('2073 6f75 6c73 a9a9 a920 636f 6d70 6172').decode('cp1252')` returns `' souls©©© compar'` or `bytes.fromhex('2073 6f75 6c73 a9a9 a920 636f 6d70 6172').decode('cp437')` -> `' souls⌐⌐⌐ compar'`…